# Word problem on practice test

Tags: word-problem

2 out of 5 students attend graduate school after college. If there are 750 seniors graduating, how many will attend graduate school? 
A)75
B)107
C)214
D)300

I answered it like this 750/2=375. But that is a full half of graduating class which would have been correct if the question was stated 2.5 out of 5 students attend graduate school. So I rounded down to the nearest answer which is 300.  I got it correct but that was just luck in my opinion because the question didn't ask to estimate. I know I didn't figure it out correctly and need someone to explain the steps. Thank you!

Comment: "2 out of 5 students attend..." means two fifth of all students attend. So it's 2/5 * 750

Answer (score 2):

Solve for $x$ : $\frac{2}{5}=\frac{x}{750}$ ... Since this may or may not explain it to all, then how about this: We are given that the amount of students who are graduating senior students (let's call this $y$) is directly proportional to the students that go to gradate school (let's call this $x$). So we are give $y=kx$ where $k$ represents the constant of proportionality. We know that $(2,5)$ is on the line $y=kx$. We can use this to find $k$. So pluggin in we get $5=k(2)$ then $k=\frac{5}{2}$. So we have the equation $y=\frac{5}{2} x$. Now we are asked to find $x$ when $y=750$ . So plug in and solve for $x$ giving us $750=\frac{5}{2} x$ which implies $x=750 \cdot \frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: In my opinion, to someone who doesn't know what's going on, this would just seem like a random mix of all the numbers we're given that doesn't even give the right answer.

Comment: In my opinion, the equation setup explains the problem itself. $x/750$ is said to be $2/5$ from the initial sentence.

Comment: Ahh, i read it as $\frac{x}{2/5}=\frac{x}{750}$ (I was taught, and now teach, "$:$" as a division symbol at school). I see now that that is not what you meant.

Comment: @Arthur do you appreciate my "more wordier" explanation? :)

Comment: Oh no... I see what you mean now I think  .  When reading my explanation:   This ":" is to be read as a colon not a division sign. I was using the fraction bar as a division sign.

Comment: 2 out of 5 (...), for 750: (2/5) * 750 = 1500 / 5 = 300.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone! I knew the answer had to be simple but as you get older and no longer use math, you get stumped by the smallest details. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

we were given the proportion $2/5$ (two out of five students). we can set this up as proportion problem. Then $x$ number of students $/750$ total number of students. So the equation must look like this:

$\frac25 = \frac{x}{750}$  (Solve for $x$)

$5x=750 \cdot2$

$5x=1500$

$x=\frac{1500}{5}$

$x=300$ so this amount of students will attend college